# Does water inside a vessel in another vessel boil?

Tags: states-of-matter

What if there are two metal containers filled with water .One floats in another.The system is heated above 100 deg celsius. What will happen?

Comment: If "the whole system is heated above 100 °C", what do you think is going to happen...?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why water inside a vessel placed in a body of boiling water does not boil?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21841)

Answer (score 0):

yes the old fashion back boiler immersion heaters did just that by heating an internal coil of water within the boiler !!!

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) Can you edit your answer a bit to elaborate more on it? As it is, it is at least for me a bit hard to understand exactly what happens in the setup you are thinking of ...